# Ebean ManyToMany Error getting BeanDescriptor

Tags: java, playframework, many-to-many, ebean

My models:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users", schema = "public")
public class User extends Model {

    @Id
    public Long id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "user_roles", schema = "public", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    public Collection < Role > roles;

}

@Entity@Table(name = "roles", schema = "public")
public class Role extends Model {

    public Role(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Role() {}

    @Id
    public Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    public Collection < User > users;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

And here is the query that I'm trying to produce:

```
User user = User.db().find(User.class).fetch("roles").where().eq("id",     id).findUnique();
```

But unfortunately getting eror that says:

> [CompletionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error getting BeanDescriptor for path roles from models.User]

Also when I'm trying to change my Collection<> models to List<> for some reason I'm getting this exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: com.avaje.ebean.common.BeanList[0]->models.Role["users"]->com.avaje.ebean.common.BeanList[0]... and so on.

Collection (fine) -> List (Exception).

What's the problem?